# Why do my popups appear upside down on iOS6 using presentViewController:animated:

Tags: ipad, ios6

In my TabBar based app on iPad, I need to display modal, popup views, which I do by calling UIViewController.presentViewController:animated:completion:

On iOS5 this works fine. But on iOS6 - when the device is upside down - the popup view appears upside down. It animates down, from the top of the display, upside down.

When I say the device is upside down, I mean LandscapeLeft (button on left) and PortraitUpsideDown (button on top). In the other two orientations, the popup animates up from the bottom, and is right side up as you would expect.

The problem occurs with all 3 of the popup views I am using in my app - 2 of them are subclasses of UIViewController and the 3rd one is the MFMailComposeViewController.

I use code like this to display the view:

```
MyModalViewController * tmpModal = [[MyModalViewController alloc] init];
tmpModal.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
tmpModal.contentSizeForViewInPopover =  CGSizeMake(350,450);

[self.tabBarController presentViewController:tmpModal
                                    animated:TRUE
                                  completion:^
                                        {


                                        }];
```

I've added the iOS6 rotation delegate methods to the 2 UIViewController based views, and it had no effect.

IE:

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

That didn't help one bit.

How can I be the only one who has experienced this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be in my UITabBarController subclass. I had accidentally overrode the getter method for "interfaceOrientation" - I had created a getter of that name but called it like a (void) method (without even looking at the return value). The method was intended to update an app-wide variable containing the current orientation and I called it from a method called viewDidRotate which is an observer of the UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification notification.

I changed the method to be called "saveInterfaceOrientation" instead (and made it a void) and the problem is gone.